# Why didn't a single language predominate China, Japan, Korea?

Tags: language-families

Because related Indo-European languages in the West spread enormously, why didn't related languages of some family (an obvious possibility is Sinitic) similarly spread through the areas that are now China, Korea, Japan? Why didn't a sole (ancestor) language preponderate over these areas? I assume nothing about what that lone language was, but Chinese feels like the most probable candidate. I'm  extending [this question on Reddit](https://redd.it/jl3t76) to Chinese.

Unquestionably China, Korea, Japan are way closer to each other than Iceland, Ireland vs. Bengal — the "polar opposite" [language borders of the Indo-European family](https://redd.it/gx2v9y). China and Korea share land borders.  The shortest  distance from Korea to Japan is 214 km, from Busan to Hakata.

I'll analogize Chinese, Japanese, Korean to Latin and Latin's devolution into the Romance Languages. Where does my analogy fail? Did the East Asians lack horses and wheeled vehicle technology of the Indo-Europeans? Korea and Japan adopted Chinese, the Chinese writing system, and culture. ["The Chinese *hanzi* is in fact Korean *hanja* and Japanese *kanji*"](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-the-Chinese-Japanese-and-Korean-languages-so-similar/answer/Jay-Trang). I know about [Sino-Korean and Sino-Japanese words](https://redd.it/7vkrll), but [Modern Japanese utilizes  Chinese characters more explicitly and readily than Modern Korean](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/3831).
Similarly, Western Europe adopted Latin, the Latin writing system, and Roman culture.

Like the Roman Empire, China has been a military, economic, and social superpower that [influenced Korea, Japan, Vietnam](https://old.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/tgv0b/eli5_the_common_origin_and_differentiation/c4mlz0f/). ["Korean and Japanese officials and intellectuals used Chinese for the official documentation, records and poems, just like British used [Norman] French in their courts for some time before their native “English” language could be widely accepted and used"](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-the-Chinese-Japanese-and-Korean-languages-so-similar/answer/Jackson-Lee-79). I'm surmising that Chinese could've been a *sprachbund* and lingua franca.

[Whether Koreanic and Japonic languages](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/21405) share a common origin is [an outstanding question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/3688) —  but this is irrelevant —  because even if they are related, the Sino-Tibetan language family is distinguished and distinct from the Koreanic/Japonic language families.

I read that the [Japanese migrated not from mainland China](https://old.reddit.com/r/linguistics/comments/28012v/japanese_and_korean_and_chinese_why_two/ci69tmt/), and "the Manchurians (related more the the Mongols and Turks than the Han Chinese) migrated to Korea, and then the Koreans crossed the straight into Japan".

[image]

Comment: Do you mean "what are the historical reasons why languages from the same family aren't spoken in China, Japan, and Korea", or "what are the linguistic reasons why those languages aren't considered to form a family", or what?

Comment: I don’t really understand your question. The analogy with Latin is quite apt, and the evolution is similar in some ways – but having a lingua franca superstrate does not make the local languages related, so I don’t see how it’s _relevant_. In Europe, the Romance and Germanic (and Slavic) languages which were most heavily influenced by Latin happened to already be related, but they weren’t mutually intelligible; in Asia, the languages that were most influenced by Chinese (Japanese, Korean, Vietnamese) happened _not_ to be already related.

Comment: you may want to read *Koreo-Japonica: A Re-evaluation of a Common Genetic Origin* by Alexander Vovin https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt6wqz03

Comment: @user52144 You cannot _make_ languages more related, just like you cannot make people more related. Relatedness is whether or not two languages (or people) originate from the same source or not, and that can’t be changed because it’s in the _past_. Your cousin is genetically related to you because you share the same grandparents – living in houses next to each other doesn’t change that.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet A second way to understand my question — If Chinese and China heavily influenced Korea and Japan, why didn't Chinese cause Korean and Japanese to become more related to Chinese than they are currently? I never wrote that any language was mutually intelligible. It's irrelevant whether Japanese, Korean, Vietnamese were already related, because my ancillary question is why Chinese didn't intertwine them more?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I rewrote my comment.  "make" was a wrong choice of words. I was asking why Korean and Japanese didn't borrow more from, or liken themselves more to, Chinese so that Modern Korean and Japanese can enter the same language family as Chinese.

Comment: @user52144 Japanese and Korean borrowed _very_ extensively from Chinese – a very large percentage of their vocabulary is Chinese in origin. But that doesn’t mean they ‘entered’ the Sino-Tibetan family. You can’t enter a language family, just like you can’t genetically enter a human family without being born into it. You can think of borrowing vocabulary as ‘marrying’ into a family if you wish – it closely aligns you with a family, but your genes won’t change to be those of that family. Family relatedness is genetic and is purely determined by past origin.

Comment: As it stands now, this is quite an interesting question – essentially, given the enormous spread of related Indo-European languages in the West, are there specific reasons why a similar spread of related languages of some family (Sinitic being an obvious option) did not spread throughout East Asia. The facetious answer is of course that it did – Chinese has spread over a vast area and ousted many other languages. But beyond that, while this is now a good question, it’s not really a _linguistic_ question; I’d say it’d be more at home on [history.se] than here now.

Comment: @Keelan Please let me keep my picture, to illustrate how widespread the Indo-European languages spread.

Comment: It's a good map.

Comment: But people know that, and it is very large. Means a lot of scrolling and bandwidth. Maybe shrink it to 100px in height if you really think it's useful?

Comment: China itself is a hybrid conglomerate though fixed culture, but it was not a mobile culture like the Mongolian, nor very expansionistic, nor a melting pot. Such is more the case for the Malaysian spreading. Your question targets a feasible time, just very early, where my European ancestors probably still lived in caves.

Answer (score 5):

The OPs comments clarify an erroneous assumption – "why didn't Chinese cause Korean and Japanese to become more related to Chinese than they are currently?" and "I was asking why Korean and Japanese didn't borrow more from, or liken themselves more to, Chinese so that Modern Korean and Japanese can enter the same language family as Chinese".

In the genetic concept of language family, languages are not "adopted" into a language family. In this view of language relationships, Tamil is a member of the Dravidian language family and is not a member of the Indo-European family, despite the huge number of Sanskrit loan words into Tamil. Swahili is a Bantu language and always has been on, regardless of the influence of Arabic.

Some languages do not have a single ancestor, in particular [pidgins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pidgin) and their offspring creoles, where the former arises by groups of adults needing to communicate with no common language, and they concoct a limited language. In that situation, we would not say that the resulting language is a "member of a family", but it could be the start of a new language family.

The OP also suggests that "language spread" could somehow be relevant to there being a single language family. This may be true, in the sense that when one language spreads, it may obliterate indigenous languages. The expansion of English, Spanish and Portuguese in the New World are a prime case of that happening. The explanation for why language A did not obliterate languages B or C is not linguistic, it is social and historical. The [continental Celtic languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continental_Celtic_languages) were obliterated as a result of the expansion of other tribes (Romans, primarily). The Germanic language English was not obliterated as a result of the Norman conquest: one should look for social and historical explanations for the differences.

Answer (score 3):

Because there were neolithic agricultural speakers of extinct language families beside PST people, their technologies were even more advanced. Look at Hongshan, Dawenkou and Liangzhu cultures.
Some families might survive until today, probably including Hmong-Mien, Kra-Dai and Koreanic.

About Dongyi (Eastern Yi peoples): There were technically advanced peoples occupying coastal eastern China, especially in Shandong and Jiangsu.
I've seen some basic words which have problems to be traced back to PST, but have correspondence with Middle or Old Korean:

风（風）*prəm "wind" vs MK polom,

江 *kˤroŋ "river" vs MK kolom,

木 *C.mˤok "tree" vs OK namok

Some words above are also present in Austroasiatic and/or Austro-Tai, but they couldn't affect Proto-Koreanic so much into basic vocabulary. I personally suspect these words were originally loans from extinct Dongyi languages, being borrowed into adjacent families.